# qtip2,when I scroll modal but tips not follow modal

Tags: qtip2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hR5Ct.png)

qtip2,when I scroll modal but tips not follow modal

Comment: picture above on description

Comment: Please post your code, and tell us what you have already tried?